# Outlook "Disable hardware graphics acceleration" moved?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Using latest Office365 Outlook, I don't have "Disable hardware graphics acceleration" under "Advanced" anymore.

Did Microsoft move it? I can't find it.

Thanks

Update:
Version Microsoft® Outlook® til Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14026.20202) 64-bit

Update:
Here's a screenshot (sorry that it is in Dansih), but the "Display" section is gone:

[image]

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: Microsoft® Outlook® til Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14026.20202) 64-bit

Comment: You're a few minor versions ahead of me, perhaps they deprecated it. I can see it under Advanced > Display, alongside 'Play animated GIFs'.

Comment: I have no "Display" section anymore.

Comment: I would raise a record on https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: That function is Office-Wide and I still see it in Outlook, Excel and Word.   Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13929.20360) 64-bit.  I will watch the next versions.

Comment: Version Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14026.20202) 64-bit  just now - same as the OP.   Disable Hardware Graphics is still there. Try repairing Office.

Answer (score 0):

The update to Office (16.0.14026.20202) 64-bit took a long time on two machines here, including a somewhat lengthy pause between downloading and updating.

I let both machines to update completely and both Office installations include the option to Disable Hardware Graphics in the "normal" location - that is, the option was not moved.

Please see the screen shot.

[image]

It is possible the update did not complete properly because it took so long to complete.

Try updating again and then if the option is not there as shown, try doing a full repair of Office.

This is for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14026.20202) 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests on Outlook 365 version 2105:
[image]

I still could find the option like below:
[image]

So what's the specific version of your Outlook client, it's recommended to update your Outlook to latest version to check if the issue has any difference(File>office account>update options>update now).

Comment: So what's the specific version of your Outlook client,  <-- I am using the same version as the OP  16.0.14026.20202) 64-bit